# Making whole <td> Clickable through anchor tag

Tags: css, html-table, href, html-email, newsletter

While creating an html email for Outlook, I stumbled upon a small problem that I have not been able to fix.

Below is a screen shot of an html table. I need to make the whole area clickable and not just the text.  When I put `<a href="#">` around the `<td>` or `<table>` it works in  browsers but not in Outlook.

[image]

Here is the code:

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-top-left-radius: 5px;border-top-right-radius: 5px;border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;background-color: #2FBA45;border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td align="center" valign="middle" style="font-family: Arial;font-size: 22px;padding: 15px;border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;">
                <a href="#" title="Yes please, send me a quote." target="_self" style="font-weight: bold;letter-spacing: -0.5px;line-height: 100%;text-align: center;text-decoration: none;color: #FFFFFF;word-wrap: break-word !important; display:block; width:100%; height:100%">Yes please, send me a quote.</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Check out this link to see what HTML standards eMail clients support http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Comment: @AnaMaria  i know it but i am  asking for alternate of this code  if possible

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but I was looking for an answer to this problem (clickable whole buttons in Outlook) and stumbled upon the following solution:

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td align="center" valign="middle" >

<!-- start of Outlook compatible button generated by http://buttons.cm/ -->
<div><!--[if mso]>
  <v:roundrect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" href="http://yoururlhere.com/" style="height:52px;v-text-anchor:middle;width:330px;" arcsize="10%" stroke="f" fillcolor="#2fba45">
    <w:anchorlock/>
    <center>
  <![endif]-->
      <a href="http://yoururlhere.com/"
style="background-color:#2fba45;border-radius:5px;color:#ffffff;display:inline-block;font-family:sans-serif;font-size:13px;font-weight:bold;line-height:52px;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;width:330px;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;">Yes please, send me a quote.</a>
  <!--[if mso]>
    </center>
  </v:roundrect>
<![endif]--></div>
<!-- end of Outlook compatible button generated by http://buttons.cm/ -->

            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Note I have not tested the above code.

Other answers did link to the campaignmonitor website, but not [this link which provided the solution](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/3920/bulletproof-background-images-and-buttons-email-newsletters).

That blog post at campaignmonitor mentions that they have created a [specific website to generate outlook compatible clickable buttons - http://buttons.cm](http://buttons.cm/)  based on a solution created by Stig M (@stigm on twitter).

I do not work for campaignmonitor.

Hope that helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

try this

http://jsfiddle.net/KrRzP/

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"   style="border-top-left-radius: 5px;border-top-right-radius: 5px;border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;background-color: #2FBA45;border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt; cursor:pointer;">
    <tbody>                 
        <tr>
            <td align="center" valign="middle"  style="font-family: Arial;font-size: 22px;padding: 15px;border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;">
                <a  href="http://www.example.org" title="Yes please, send me a quote."  target="_self" style="font-weight: bold;letter-spacing: -0.5px;line-height: 100%;text-align: center;text-decoration: none;color: #FFFFFF;word-wrap: break-word !important; display:block; width:100%; height:100%">Yes please, send me a quote.</a>
            </td>  
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: its not working even in browsers , is there anyway i  change  my code like span etc to get same output ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the `onClick`, `<td onClick="go to anchor">`. In the inline style you should add `cursor: pointer` so the cursor is changed to the 'hover a link'-pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `target="_self"`. As Outlook is a email client, it probably doesn't recognize it and may be causing the issue.

On a side note, If you are using anchor links within your email (linking elsewhere on the same page), this is not fully supported in all email browsers. Here is the [support chart](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/3322/the-trouble-with-anchor-links-in-email-newsletters/)

Answer (score 0):

Use JavaScript "**innerHTML**" property. By default, in HTML5 you cannot directly add an anchor  tag in a table cell  element.

```
<html>
<title>
</title>
<head>
</head>
<body>

    <table>
        <thead>
             <tr>
                 <td>Youtube</td>
                 <td id="assign_anchor_tag_here"></td>
            </tr>
        <thead>
    </table>

<script>
    var td_element = document.getElementById("assign_anchor_tag_here");
    td_element.innerHTML = "<a href='https://www.youtube.com'>Click Here!</a>";
</script>
```